# Cordova XMLHttpRequest.status=0 when try to get data from web service on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I got XMLHttpRequest.status=0 when try to get data from my web service on Android device via Cordova 6.4.0. Request works on Nexus Emulator, but not on real device.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:58511/api/OrdersApi',  
            success: function (data) {
                  WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                alert(XMLHttpRequest.status + '\n' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + '\n' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

If I replace URL just for testing to Nasa API: `url: "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY",` It works on device. Web service side code:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class OrdersApiController : ApiController
{
 // code for get CRUD operations
}
```

That's what i put to  in index.html regarding CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Here what I tried to do in config.xml:

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
  <access origin="http://localhost:58511*"/>
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
    <access origin="http://localhost:58511*"/>
    <access origin="*" />
  </platform>
```

Comment: Have you whitelisted the URI in your config.xml? Also make sure your CSP (content-security-policy) meta tag allows the URI as well.

Comment: Could you please give more details. In 'config.xml' on client I put '<access origin="*" />'  And about CSP... Is it on Web service or client side?

Comment: CSP is client-side, specified in index.html. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

Comment: Is the whitelist plugin added to your project as well? (Should also be listed in your config.xml)

Comment: added config.xml on the top

Comment: Where is the backend located? Your dev machine? If so, don't use `localhost` -- use your dev machine's IP address, and make sure that your machine is on the same network as your device.

Also: you've got a lot of duplicate entries in that config.xml -- I would suggest removing the duplicates. Also, instead of `http://localhost:58511*`, use `http://localhost:58511/*` (with the slash). But again, note that `localhost` will refer to the _device_ and *not* your backend.

Comment: @Kerri Shotts, switched from localhost to machine's IP, checked if IP can be reached from device and now it works. Thanks a much!